# Deploy a mondrian schema in pentaho 5.1 without schema workbench

Tags: pentaho, data-warehouse, mondrian

I have a question, in pentaho 5.1, how can I deploy a cube without using the schema workbench? I'm kind of newbie in Pentaho. 
Is there a cmd line? Java code? Or something like...
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in the User Console.

There is a menu Manage Data source...   There you can upload your xml and refer to a database connection for it.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suppose you have installed BA Server and have made at least **fact table**.
In case you don't know what the fact table is, or someone else is reading this answer, you can find brief explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fact_table).
Of course, it's better to have full [Star Schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema). You cannot create [Snow Flake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_schema) inside Pentaho User Console. You can create it with Pentaho Schema Workbench or by manually edit mondarian.xml.

Make sure that your JDBC driver is inside BA Server driver directory. [Look!](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help48/index.jsp?topic=%2Fadmin_guide%2Fconcept_adding_a_jdbc_driver.html) Open Pentaho User Console. It's by default at localhost:8080/pentaho or yourdomain.name:8080/pentaho and login as administrator

1. File -> New -> Data Source
2. Choose Data source
3. Type Choose fact table and define connections to dimensions (if exists)
4. Choose to modify cube on the end of data source wizard

   .

Comment: You can create a snow flake without PSW. PSW simply generates a XML file. You can create that same XML file by hand. Just add your dimensions as joins between tables and you have your snow flake.

Comment: @nsousa I meant to that he can't make Snow Flake inside PUC. As I understand well, he asked for an easier way. I will edit my answer.

Comment: ok, fair point. I never use PUC to create schemas, I find it highty limited, sometimes I forget you can even do it there.

Comment: And it's really great for base xml. Define measures and how they look like, time dimension with all annotations. Later you can add security properties, caclulated measures, expand it to snow flake in PSW..